# How to treat nested entity add/update/delete operations in Hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, kotlin, jpa

I once again joined a project which uses Hibernate (Spring/Hibernate/Kotlin to be exact) and have read through a number of Vlad Mihalcea wonderful articles to refresh my knowledges about this ORM ([this](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) article is of my current interest).

What I'm trying to understand is how should I treat add/update/delete operations for nested entities (bidirectional @OneToMany). Here is what I don't understand.

Say we have a `Post` entity:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
class Post(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,
    val title: String,

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private val comments: MutableList<PostComment> = MutableList<PostComment>()
) {
    fun addComment(comment: PostComment) {
        comments.add(comment)
        comment.post = this
    }

    fun removeComment(comment: PostComment) {
        comments.remove(comment)
        comment.post = null
    }
}
```

And a `PostComment` entity:

```
@Entity(name = "PostComment")
@Table(name = "post_comment")
class PostComment(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    var id: Long? = null,
    val review: String,

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    var post: Post
) {
    override fun equals(o: Any?): Boolean {
        if (this === o) return true
        if (o !is PostComment) false
        return id != null && id == o.id
    }

    override fun hashCode(): Int {
        return javaClass.hashCode()
    }
}
```

All in all everything is good, but here is the couple of things I don't know how to cover:

1. In fact `Post` class won't compile since I set `post` field of `PostComment` to null while it is not nullable. What is a good practice to handle it? Should I make all relations nullable in kotlin just because hibernate require it to be so and it is in contradiction with business logic?
2. It is more or less clear how to add and delete nested entities, though what should we do if we need to update already existing nested entity. Let's imagine we have a `Post(id=1, title="lovely post", comments=[PostComment(id=15, review="good", post=this)]` and we get a update action with the following `PostDto(id=1, title="not that nice post", comments=[PostComment(id=15, review="bad", post=this)]`. As you can see we need to update `title` for `Post` and `review` for `PostComment`. If we take a look at the Vlad's article I linked above we do not see any update methods. I think it was just ommited since it is not related to article topic.
   But I wonder what is the good practice to handle such an update? Something like these two approaches comes to my mind but I'm not sure if these are the best things to do:

```
@Entity(name = "Post")
@Table(name = "post")
class Post(
    //fields...
) {

    fun addComment(comment: PostComment) {
        comments.add(comment)
        comment.post = this
    }

    fun removeComment(comment: PostComment) {
        comments.remove(comment)
        comment.post = null
    }

    // not effective, since issue delete/insert queries, but clean
    fun updateComment(comment: PostComment) {
        val commentId = comment.id!!
        comments.removeIf { it.id == commentId }
        comment.team = this
    }

    // effective, since issue only update query, but dirty as hell
    fun updateComment(commentId: Long, review: String) {
        val comment = comments.find { it.id == commentId }!!
        comment.review = review
    }
}
```

3. Not actual anymore. Refer good explanation by @Chris in a comment section.
   <strike>Imagine we need an endpoint to update a comment only. What
   is the best way to organise our code base for such a scenario?
   Should we always update it like this (always fetch old post, looks
   inefficient) or is there any better/efficient approach?</strike>

```
@Transactional
fun reassignComment(newPostId: Long, commentDto: CommentDto) {
   val comment = commentRepo.findByIdOrNull(commentDto.id)!!
   val oldPost = comment.post
   val newPost = postRepo.findByIdOrNull(newPostId)!!
   oldPost.removeComment(comment)
   newPost.addComment(comment)
}
```

Thanks anyone for your time and input!

Comment: Hibernate/JPA does not require you to set something as nullable if it shouldn't be null - where did you get that as a requirement? If your PostComment requires a Post, why are you nulling it out - what do you want to happen when you remove a postComment from a post?

Comment: @Chris I'm maybe missing something but I saw a lot of articles including the one I mentioned in my post. AFAIU it is recommended to do to remove bidirectional link between two entities to help hibernate make optimal queries.

Comment: Get it to work before you work on optimization, but I don't see how that forces you to make something nullable. Nothing here forces you to set PostComment.post to null if you don't want to and the column is not-null in the DB. I think you might be making some preemptive and wrong assumptions that might be leading your app into problems - JPA will automatically delete PostComment if it is dereferenced from a Post without any need for you to handle the PostComment->Post reference.  For updates cascading - JPA merge (spring save) should handle that. Try it!

Comment: As for #3 - you shouldn't have orphan removal set on Post->PostCommit if you want to move PostCommit instances around to different posts. Setting that option means you want JPA to delete any PostCommit instances once they are dereferenced from a Post - so they are essentially dependent and exist ONLY with their parent Post (once associated anyway). You can make it work by setting ONLY the PostComment->Post relationship, but it isn't advisable (and you have to deal with any cached post instances being stale/out of synch with the database yourself).

Comment: It actually works already and we faced the issue when `postComment` collection is fully exposed for usage and one developer updated these links with consecutive `clear` and `addAll` calls which resulted in A LOT of requests to DB. That's why I want to create some defensive API for our entity objects.

Comment: Regarding your point for #3. You are right, let's not consider this in a discussion.  Thank you!

Comment: Actually, #2 remained the only significant part of my question, let me edit my question.